# update a set inside a dict comprehension?

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have two dicts, that share the same keys but have distinct values. Each value is a set like this:

```
d1 = {'a': set(["a","b","c"]), 'b': set(["x","y","c"])} 
d2 = {'a': set(["a","b","yu"]), 'b': set(["x","y","ri"])}
```

I would like to create a new dict, `d3` that contains the same keys as `d1` and `d2`, but with values that are the result of update each set of `d1[key]` with `d2[key]`, I would like to do this inside a dict comprehension, something like:

```
d3 = {k: d1[k].update(d2[k]) for k in d1}
```

However, the result of:

```
d1[k].update(d2[k])
```

Of course is `None`, and I get a dict like:

```
d3 = {'a':None, 'b':None}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: could you provide the expected output please?

Comment: update() changes dict in place, it does not returns updated dict. Return value is None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` is the in-place version. The method that returns a new set and leaves the original unchanged is `union`; alternatively, you can use the `|` operator

```
d3 = {k: d1[k].union(d2[k]) for k in d1}
# or
d3 = {k: d1[k] | d2[k] for k in d1}
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Whoops, forgot the keys. Thanks.

Comment: @user2357112: better still; I echoed the OP using a string.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I'm not sure

```
d3 = {k: d1[k] | d2[k] for k in d1}
```